# Ubuntu crashes every time I connect the computer to HDMI

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hdmi

Every time I connect my computer to my TV via HDMI, my computer's screen goes black and Ubuntu crashes.  I use Ubuntu 15.10, and my laptop is an ASUS with an Nvidia GeForce 840M graphics card.  Windows works fine.

Have you ever seen this behavior before? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Install the proprietary drivers from Nvidia, since using proprietary drivers will most likely give you a boost and probably fix your issue.  I don't know a lot about Nvidia since I am an AMD user, but at least for me, installing the proprietary drivers fixed all of my issues.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm pretty sure the driver is updated, but I'm going to look on that direction.